# declaring a generic func for all rest api services

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, objectmapper

i'm trying to write a generic func that takes url and T model object then creates a GET request and returns the object.

when I call my func error : Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

```
override viewdidload(){

        companyRequest(company: Company, urlString: url)  // error is here

}

  fileprivate func companyRequest<T:Mappable>(company:T,urlString:String){



        guard let url=URL(string: urlString) else {return}

        print(url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let response = response {

                let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse


                switch  (responseCode?.statusCode)!  {

                case 200,201 :

                    print(data!)
                    let content = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: data)
                    print(content?.toJSON())
                    //self.getCompanysuccessfull(data: data!,T)
                    //self.completion(true,code!)
                    break
                case 400,500,404 :
                    self.DisplayError(errorCode: (responseCode?.statusCode)!)
                    break

                default :
                    self.DisplayError(errorCode: (responseCode?.statusCode)!)

                }

            }
            }.resume()



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make two changes...

When defining a function that take a Type, you need to do:

```
func companyRequest<T: Mappable>(company: T.Type, urlString: String)
```

*As an aside, why all the references to "company" in the above declaration when this code should work with any mappable type?*

Note the `.Type` that you were missing.

Then when calling the code, you have to add `.self` like this:

```
companyRequest(company: Company.self, urlString: url)
```

Comment: did your changes still : Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred and Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue. when I fixed it companyRequest(company: Company<T:mappable>.self, urlString: url)

Comment: What version of Swift and Xcode are you using? I copy/pasted your code into a project, made my changes, and it compiles.

Comment: I'm using object Mapper not native swift code like decodable

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Swift 4.2, Xcode 10. Maybe something has changed in this area. In answer to your question, I just did `struct Company: Mappable { }`. No more is necessary to get the code to compile.